# Spring embedded Mongo DB

Tags: spring, mongodb, embedded-database

I have a project with Spring Boot and Embedded Mongo DB also i want to look up the data that has been stored there. how to that 
i followed this tutorial https://springframework.guru/spring-boot-with-embedded-mongodb/

everything works except i can not connect to the embedded DB using this mongo-express? which password and username is set? how i connect to localhost embedded db ??? after working with this tutorial?

Answer (score 0):

In order to use EmbeddedMongo in your tests, this property must be set inside application.properties.

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://localhost/test
```

You can test adding test methods to SpringBootMongodbApplicationTests.java as shown below.

```
package guru.springframework;

import guru.springframework.domain.Product;
import guru.springframework.repositories.ProductRepository;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SpringBootMongodbApplicationTests {

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {

    }

    @Test
    public void testMongoDbRepository(){
        Product product = new Product();
        product.setDescription("DESC");
        product.setImageUrl("test.png");
        product.setPrice( BigDecimal.valueOf(1500) );
        productRepository.save(product);

        long count = productRepository.count();
        Assert.assertEquals( 1, count );
        productRepository.deleteAll();
    }
}
```